# Create a slug that accepts certain characters for blog url

Tags: php

Please how do I create a slug for my php blog with a function that will accept only alphanumerics,inverted commas,commas,full stop,colon,empty spaces,_,@,#,&,*,%, currency symbols and - but replaces every other characters with a space and then replace all spaces with dash.
All assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of creating your own function, just use an existing library. It's going to be better than whatever you make yourself, and there's really no point in reinventing the wheel.

You could try out something like https://github.com/cocur/slugify , and a quick google search will give you plenty of other options as well.

Comment: @chocochaos I've done some googling b4 posting here and couldn't find something that exactly works for me.What I want is a function that retrieves the title of a clicked post & append it to the url like so: www.my site. com/blog/slug-created-from-title-of-blog

Comment: So you just append the result from Slugify to your url, that doesn't seem too hard. I have updated my answer below with an example function if you need it, but it really should not be too much of a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your own function, just use an existing library. It's going to be better than whatever you make yourself, and there's really no point in reinventing the wheel.

You could try out something like [slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify), and a quick google search will give you plenty of other options as well.

---

For your use case, a simple function to create a url with a slug, using Slugify:

```
    /**
     * @param string $urlFormat
     * @param string $postTitle
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function createUrl(string $urlFormat, string $postTitle): string
    {
        $slugify = new Slugify();
        $slug = $slugify->slugify($postTitle);
        $url = sprintf($urlFormat, $slug);

        return $url;
    }

    createUrl('http://example.com/some/path/%s', 'Hello world');
```

Please note that this example assumes you use PHP 7.0 or higher. If not, remove the type hints for the function and arguments.

Comment: You were right. The answer has been updated a bit now that OP's question has become a bit clearer.